# Base64 image uploading to server PHP

Tags: php, android

I create an android application which can take pictures and upload it to server. I send this image file using base64 encoding and send it to PHP script. How can I upload this base64 file in php script ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Retrofit for http communication on Android. http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Anyway your question is not clear at all, you are asking about the php script for uploding files or you are asking for the way to send them from android?